# Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array - riot api curl/json/php

Tags: php, json, api, curl

Im stumbling upon issues I find hard to explain myself. I have this code that usually works perfectly fine, but after I change to nested information the result always lead to `Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array`. Even if I revert everything to the old state, it keeps telling me the fatal error. I am using the RIOT API (league of legends).

```
  <?php

    ini_set("display_errors", "1"); error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/challenger?type=RANKED_SOLO_5x5&api_key=key');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

    $json = json_decode($response, true);

        foreach($json as $elem)

            {
            echo $elem[0]['entries'][0]['playerOrTeamName'];
         // echo $elem[0]['entries'][0]['miniSeries'][0]['wins'];
         // echo $elem[0]['entries'][0]['miniSeries'][0]['losses'];
            }
?>
```

Comment: `$elem[0]` or `$elem[0]['entries'][0]` is a string.

Comment: I dont understand why the [0] has also to be put after the `entries`. Could you please explain why it has to be added in order to be settled as string? Edit- i was confused, i seem to understand now. But still not working when I add echo $elem[0]['entries'][0]['playerOrTeamName'][0];

Comment: Just output `$json` variable with `var_dump`.

Comment: check 20ff.net
i have disabled all echoes now. var_dump($json) is now active. The code is working before the error popped up but now it does not anymore. I have no clue why.

Comment: What your trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to echo some results of the full api request. Finding player names along with win/loss numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not explored array properly.

```
foreach ($json['entries'] as $entry)
     {
     echo $entry['playerOrTeamName'] . ' wins:' . $entry['wins'] . "<br/>";
     }
```

Also, your array does not contain losses, and miniSeries.

Please, explore your data thoroughly further.